# react-redux settings implementation broke previously functioning sign up process. error 422

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, user-input, http-status-code-422

This is my situation.  I have a branch that's ahead of my master in which I created a settings view with react-redux.  I wanted to add a place for users to change their initial input info.  When I added and connected this view, my site broke.  I used to be able to 'sign up' a new user.  Now I can't.  When I click submit in the sign up view, nothing happens other than that I get a 422 error in the console.

I'm using an API that thinkster.io provides.  I have no idea where to start on this one... Below is a link to my repo.  I see the LONG warning about changing thew input state as well... could that be why this is not working.  Even when this was working before I incorporated the settings page, I would frequently have to refresh the page upon starting my server.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Been stuck on this for too long!

> http://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects/tree/monday

Comment: (is that the proper way to provide access to a specific branch here?) No. You linked a commit log. We would need access to the actual code, not just commit changes.

Comment: thank you.  once I figure out, I will edit the message above.  So is this whats needed?  

https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects/tree/monday

or is the general link found under the clone option what's right to provide... which is this

https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects.git

Comment: Yeah your first link is good!

Comment: awesome.  thanks dude.

Comment: did I do it?  I think my dumb code stumped stack overflow.  There is not much info about this error on the web.  But I think my problem lies in how my errors while logging in are being sent.  My error code has an error?!

Comment: 422 error code means [Unprocessable Entity](https://httpstatuses.com/422) which points me in the direction of the issue being with the API. The content type they are returning doesn't match what you specify in the request. [Here are some pointers on how to fix it](https://www.keycdn.com/support/422-unprocessable-entity/), but looks like it's usually unique to the specific app.

Comment: Hey.  Thanks for the response Chase.  I'm a noob.  I actually have been tinkering with this and found earlier today that I was missing a </fieldset> closing tag.  I can no do everything as expected. Except, I get a warning now in the settings area that `value for prop textarea shouldn't be null.`  Then upon saving new settings, regardless of what section.. ie- if I change my username or bio or both, I get `POST https://conduit.productionready.io/api/user 404 (Not Found)'  as well as another error that reads 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of null`

Comment: ...I was getting this error before and it was due to my not using the back tick character instead of normal single quotes for string interpolation when providing the API URL.  I remember changing my normal quotes to the back tick (button right above tab)  fixed that routing problem.  So I am back with a new but hopefully simpler problem to fix!  Any ideas? Here's my new repo for today with the updates.  Notice you will not be able to sign up a new user and attempt to edit their settings!  [REPO](https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects/tree/thursday)

Comment: Haha okay, I think you'd be better off creating a new question for this new issue. You'll get more support from the whole community instead of just me!

Comment: ok.  great.  Will do.  Thanks!